# glibc fails with "get-dynamic-info.h:45: undefined reference to `_DYNAMIC'"

Tags: gcc, gnu, glibc

I was building gnu C/C++ compiler tools under windows 7 using Cygwin environment.
I am getting following errors while building the glibc .  I have tried glibc 2.23  through glibc 2.30  sources.
During building all of them linker shows the same error : undefined reference to `_DYNAMIC'

I am trying to build a cross tool that will run under windows that will generate linux elf executables to run on the linux OS.

I was wondering if someone can help

I used bin utils 2.30  and 2.32

Linux headers 3.xx  through 5.xx

Gcc  4.9.1   through 9.1.0
Glibc 2.23  through 2.30

target =i686-elf

## DUMP from the screen

```
mv -f /home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/elf/rtld-libc.aT /home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/elf/rtld-libc.a
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/glibc-2.23/elf'
i686-elf-gcc   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -r -o /home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os '-Wl,-(' /home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/elf/dl-allobjs.os /home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/elf/rtld-libc.a -lgcc '-Wl,-)' \
          -Wl,-Map,/home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os.map
i686-elf-gcc   -nostdlib -nostartfiles -shared -o /home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/elf/ld.so.new            \
          -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both -Wl,-z,defs        \
          /home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os -Wl,--version-script=/home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/ld.map          \
          -Wl,-soname=ld-linux.so.2                     \
          -Wl,-defsym=_begin=0
/home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: In function `elf_machine_load_address':
**/home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/glibc-2.23/elf/../sysdeps/i386/dl-machine.h:58: undefined reference to `_DYNAMIC'
/home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/build-glibc/elf/librtld.os: In function `elf_get_dynamic_info':
/home/RahmanA/src/gcc_port_4.9.1/glibc-2.23/elf/get-dynamic-info.h:45: undefined reference to `_DYNAMIC'**
```

Comment: Any reason not to use x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ?

Comment: I read the web pages regarding porting the gcc   cross compiler under windows. They all suggest that cross compiling be done under cygwin , not mingw.  I want to create a cross compiler that will be running on the pc windows  but it will generate code for linux os. It means the compiler generated  application will not run in the windows environment, but it will run under linux os